# SQL Find and display possible duplicates

Tags: sql

I am fairly new with SQL, and this is probably an easy thing to do, but I have been looking for a question that answer this problem without success.

I have a table, let's call it "Customers", like so:

```
**Customers**
-Customer_id
-Name
-Address
-City
-State
-Zip
-Phone
```

The thing is it might have duplicate customers, so I want to write a query that **will list all customers where there is another customer with the same phone number**, and display the following fields:

> Customer Name, State, Phone, DuplicateCustomer Name, Duplicate
>   Customer State, Duplicate Customer Phone

I have tried the following statement, but it does not work

```
SELECT Name, State, Phone FROM Customers
GROUP BY Phone
HAVING COUNT (Phone)>1;
```

I can see the phone numbers that are repeated using

```
SELECT Phone FROM Customers
GROUP BY Phone
HAVING COUNT(Phone)>1
```

Also, as suggested, we can not assume they have identical value in the id field, since this simulates a case with poor data entry policies and the id's are normally auto-assigned.

So I think this is the direction I am supposed to go, and probably use the 'AS' keyword to display the 'duplicate customer' fields, but from here I am lost, I hope you can point me in the right way. Thanks.

Comment: What's the DBMS you're using?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select other columns than the ones you group by or aggregate then you could do this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers
WHERE Phone in
(
    SELECT Phone 
    FROM Customers
    GROUP BY Phone
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

Comment: This works, if I change the * for Name, State, Phone it is almost what I want, since it shows only the clients wich phone number appears more that once. Can I show them in the format that I want? I mean, grouping the same phone number in 1 column. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If `Customer_id` has identical value, them you can use `exists` :

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1 
              from customers c1 
              where c1.Phone = c.Phone and 
                    c1.Customer_id <> c.Customer_id
             );
```

Comment: Sadly we can not assume they have identical value in the id field, since this simulates a case with poor data entry policies and the id's are normally auto-assigned, but thanks for the suggestion, I will edit the question clarifying this

Answer (score 0):

Try this with EXISTS operator

```
SELECT Name, State, Phone FROM Customers c
where EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM Customers c1 on c1.phone=c.phone
GROUP BY Phone
HAVING COUNT(Phone)>1)
```

Comment: It says that a JOIN clause is required before ON

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution is the `exists` suggested by Yogesh Sharma.  But if that doesn't work, then window functions are a good alternative:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by phone) as cnt
      from customers c
     ) c
where cnt > 1
```